# Find Control next to particular tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table and inside the table i have 10 rows i want to find a particular row based on id and also i want to find other rows next to it.

example

```
    <table>
       <tr>1</tr>
       <tr>2</tr>
       <tr>3</tr>
       <tr id="CurrentId">4</tr>
       <tr>
          <td>5</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>6</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>7</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>8</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>9</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>10</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
```

In the above example i want to find value 4 based on the id "CurrentId" then i want to travel all the tr next to the id and get the values. In the above example i just mentioned 10 but in real time i dont know how many tr will be generated. so i want to get all the values next to the id. Please any one help me on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use id selector to select row and next to get next and nextAll to get next row/rows. You also have to add tds in first for rows as you can not put text directly to tr.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kSDfP/)**

```
currentRow = $('#CurrentId')
nextRow = $('#CurrentId').next()
nextAllRows = $('#CurrentId').nextAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of getting it for this example.

```
var vals = [];

$('#CurrentId').nextAll().each(function(){
    vals.push($(this).children().html());
});

console.log(vals.join(","));

//output
//5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Here's a <kbd>[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p337/aFKsj/)</kbd> to demonstrate.

I updated the fiddle to only get the first-td, by specifying a selector for the child:

```
vals.push($(this).children("td:first-child").html());
```

You may not need that; I'll leave it to you.